# Unable to locate package source

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation, dreamspark

I'm trying to get Visual Studio 2012 (Ultimate) installed, but about a quarter of the way through the install I get an message saying `Unable to locate package source`.

The file it is looking for is `WebDeploy_x64.msi`. I went to Microsoft's site and downloaded Web Deploy 3.0, but I have no idea what it did because the install *still* cannot find the file.

I downloaded Visual Studio Web through my school on Microsoft Dreamspark.

I even installed the Visual Studio update as the help section suggested. Still nothing. Google searches have proven fruitless, so if anyone has any suggestions please share them, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you do not have the required security certificate installed on your system, hence the installer cannot connect to Microsoft's server to download the package.

There are a couple of solutions to this:

- Install Visual Studio 2012 by downloading the complete installer package from Dreamspark. If your school has Dreamspark Premium, you need the 
  `Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 32-bit (English) - DreamSpark` installer and not the web version:

[image]

Dreamspark Standard:

[image]

- Install [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) *then* start the Visual Studio installer, don't try to point the installer to the Web Deploy installer because it'll fail.

Comment: Thanks mate. I got too frustrated and tried to install premium instead and I had a successful install. Is there a reason Premium installed flawlessly with the web installer and Ultimate didn't? And is there a convenient way to upgrade, would I just repeat the install process for Ultimate the way you demonstrated? I don't think I need to upgrade, but if I get it for free, why not?

Comment: @ZFN7 It might be that the download of Ultimate uses a different server to that of Premium. I'm trying to install Professional and have the same issue, so I can confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading ISO / DVD solved this odd behaviour for me. It seems some security certificates in my PC or expired links didn't allow the online web installer to function properly.